# How to prevent the loss of Jumplist items when LibreOffice is upgraded?

Tags: windows-7, libreoffice, jumplist

Every time LibreOffice is upgraded, all the Jumplist items which were manually added for each application within the suite are deleted.

The operating system is Windows 7 SP1.

Is there a way to prevent the loss of all manually added Jumplist items when LibreOffice is upgraded?

Comment: The jumplists are stored in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations.` and `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations` so you could try saving these and restoring them after the upgrade ... and [JumpListsView] might help you to identify which files belong to libreoffice. See [How to fix a broken/empty Jump List on Windows 7](How to fix a broken/empty Jump List on Windows 7) for more info about these files.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks David.  Great info.  FYI, the links in your comment are broken, if you want to post you comment again (too late to edit it).

Comment: Oops. so you could try saving these and restoring them after the upgrade ... and [JumpListsView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/jump_lists_view.html) might help you to identify which files belong to libreoffice. See [How to fix a broken/empty Jump List on Windows 7](https://angrytechnician.wordpress.com/2010/05/24/how-to-fix-a-brokenempty-jump-list-in-windows-7/) for more info about these files

Comment: @DavidPostill There you go! :-)  Thanks!

Comment: No problem ;) Let us know how it works out. I don't mind if you use the info from my comment in a self-answer if you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're speaking of
Bug 76131 - Existing pinned icon on Win7/8 is taskbar invalid after re-installation/update (https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=76131)

Please make your voice heard there.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard, so did DavidPostill's suggestion work for you?